# Do the modules over a Hopf algebra in a braided monoidal category form a monoidal category?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, hopf-algebras

Given a (strict) braided monoidal category $(\mathcal{C},\otimes,I)$ with braiding $b$ and a Hopf algebra $H$ in $\mathcal{C}$. There is a category Rep($H$) of modules over $H$ in $\mathcal{C}$. Do these have a canonical monoidal structure? My candidate for an action on $X\otimes Y$ for $H$-modules $X$ and $Y$ is
\begin{equation}
\rho_{X\otimes Y}:=(\rho_X\otimes\rho_Y)\circ(1\otimes b_{A,X}\otimes 1)\circ(\Delta\otimes 1\otimes1).
\end{equation}
The problem is that I can not quite show that it is an action. Perhaps it is only true for symmetric monoidal categories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is true in a braided monoidal category and your candidate for the action is correct.

A reference is Proposition 2.5 in

**Majid, Shahn.** Algebras and Hopf algebras in braided categories. *Advances in Hopf algebras* (Chicago, IL, 1992), 55--105, Lecture Notes in Pure and Appl. Math., **158**, Dekker, New York, 1994.

Comment: Or look at [Majid, Shahn. Braided groups. J. Pure Appl. Algebra 86 (1993), no. 2, 187--221]. Lemma 1.1. is a comodule version though

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for.